# Drawing chemical reactions

Tags: chemfig, mhchem, chemistry

I am trying to draw reactions like this [image]

I tried it like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
  \ce{ \chemfig{CH_3-CH (-[2]OH)-CH_3}  + HI -> \chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[:90]I)-CH_3} + H2O}

\end{document}
```

the result looks very messy
.So how do i accomplish making such structures  by showing only one bond between OH and Carbon at reactant and one bond at iodine and Carbon at product?
[image]

Comment: With `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}` you will obtain result aw hand wroted in your question.

Comment: @Zarko Can you please give the code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want this result, right?

[image]

Then `CH3CHCH3` must be considered as *one* group of 6 atoms (C, H, C, H, C and H) where the bond is leaving from the third atom. You need to tell this to `chemfig` using the bond's optional argument `<departure>`:

```
<bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,<arrival>,<tikz>]
```

The code then is `\chemfig{CH_3CHCH_3-[2,,3]OH}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{ \chemfig{CH_3CHCH_3-[2,,3]OH} + HI -> \chemfig{CH_3CHCH_3-[2,,3]I} + H2O}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `\ce` command, that will fix the links. The arrow is done with the command `\arrow`.

Also remember to enclose it between `\schemestart` and `\schemestop`.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3}\chemfig{CH(-[2]OH)}\chemfig{CH_3} + HI \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)\chemfig{CH_3(-[2]I)}\chemfig{CH CH_3} + \chemfig{H_2O}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey i don't want to show the bonds between CH3-CH-CH3 please ?  I want to show single covalent bond between CH and OH only

Comment: @aftershock [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wosbx.png)?

Comment: Yes but OH bond should be in second carbon as i have shown in post picture . it is nearly same :) but that bond should be in second carbon

Comment: @aftershock See answer

Comment: Thanks Can't we do same thing using only one chemfig for one compound?

Comment: .+ why we are using mid east and mid west ? cannot understand really :(

Comment: @clemens thanks :) but is it possible to explain shortly how CH_3CHCH_3(-[2,,3]OH) this works? why not CH_3-CH (-[2]OH)-CH_3?

Comment: @aftershock I thought you didn't want the bonds between those. If you don't use them, the only way is to use multiple `\chemfig`. I tried searching the manual for something alternative but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The `mid east` and `mid west` are needed for the arrow to be properly placed. If you only use `\arrow`, it will appear above.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that your code work well with `[version=3]{mhchem}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}% <---
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
  \ce{ \chemfig{CH_3-CH (-[2]OH)-CH_3}  + HI -> \chemfig{CH_3-CH(-[:90]I)-CH_3} + H2O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but i want to make it abit easier but removed single bonds between ch3-ch-ch3  i want to show only bonds between OH and CH :)

Comment: but isn't it abit odd to use old versions ?

Comment: @afterschock, yes, it is. But my experiences show, that sometimes new versions has new bugs or at least glitches and not completely compatible with old files. To renew them to new syntax is far more odd, I'm afraid. Probably some one, who is more experienced with `chem` packages, should wrote to author of packages about this problem.