# Bonding to specific element letter using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Im trying to reproduce this molecule using chemfig,

[image: The molecule I want to reproduce.]

I have the basic structure with this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig{*6((-F)=-*6(-(-*6(=-=-=-))=*6(-=(-F)-(=O)-=-)--O--)=-=(-^{-}O)-)}
\schemestop
\end{figure}
```

Yielding this

[image: This is the main structure of the molecule that I've generated. It is still uncomplete.]

But cannot generate the `({-}^OCCH)_2 N` part and the `OCH_2C=OO^{-}`.
The closest I can get is

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\schemestart
\chemfig{O=[:-90]{(^{-}OCCH_2)_2}|N}
\schemestop
\end{figure}
```

[image: Generated chemical compound. I want the O= bond to the first C on the left.]

But the bond does not arrive at the leftside `C`. 
Is it there a way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `\chemfig{{(}^{-}OCCH_2{)}_2N(=[2,,3]O)}`

Comment: I have more or less answered this already here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252176/5049

Comment: @clemens Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @clemens Your cited answer is not "more or less", it is actually the answer I was looking for. I haven't found that information on the `chemfig` manual until I saw the keyword _departure_ of a bond in your cited answer. Many thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the same as in [Drawing chemical reactions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252141):

> Then `CH3CHCH3` must be considered as *one* group of 6 atoms (C, H, C,
>   H, C and H) where the bond is leaving from the third atom. You need to
>   tell this to `chemfig` using the bond's optional argument
>   `<departure>`:
>
> ```
> <bond>[<angle>,<length factor>,<departure>,<arrival>,<tikz>]
> ```
>
> The code then is `\chemfig{CH_3CHCH_3-[2,,3]OH}`

In your case:

```
\chemfig{{(}^{-}OCCH_2{)}_2N(=[2,,3]O)}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!, your answer is what I was looking for, it works like charm, and even applied this to other compounds in other related molecules.